# Why does the drawer not animate on the way out?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I want my drawer to animate on the way in, and on the way out and when the animation ends, to turn to `display: none` but when the drawer is closed, it disappears and doesn't animate out.

```
const Drawer = ({ closeDrawer, isDrawerOpen }) => {
  const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState()
  let drawerClassName
  if (isDrawerOpen) {
    drawerClassName = "drawer-in"
  } else if (!isDrawerOpen && isAnimating) {
    drawerClassName = "drawer-animating"
  } else if (!isDrawerOpen && !isAnimating) {
    drawerClassName = "drawer-out"
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`drawer ${drawerClassName}`}
        onAnimationStart={() => setIsAnimating(true)}
        onAnimationEnd={() => setIsAnimating(false)}
      ></div>
      <div onClick={closeDrawer}></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

CSS:

```
.drawer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.drawer-in {
  animation: 0.7s drawerIn;
  transform: translateX(0);
  display: block;
}

.drawer-animating {
  animation: 0.7s drawerOut;
  display: block;
}

.drawer-out {
  animation: 0.7s drawerOut;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes drawerIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  1% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes drawerOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  99% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because the Drawer is closed immediately after calling {closeDrawer}. Maybe you need to add setTiomeout and then to call that.

Answer (score 0):

it's because when you set the `drawer-out` class to the element `display: none;` is activated immediately and you don't see the animation.
One solution is to run a `setTimeout` function within your JavaScript to wait for the animation to finish, then change the elements display property to `none`.  This will allow your 'closing animation' to complete before removing the element.  See my snippet below for working example.

Basically what's happening in my example snippet is I'm triggering the closing animation by adding a class associated with the animation.  Then I'm setting a time out function that waits for the animation to complete (set time out in milliseconds to match your animation time within your CSS).  Once the timeout is complete, the animation class is removed and the element's data attribute is set to `closed` which will trigger the display none.  Hope this helps.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu_toggle');
menuToggle.checked=false

menuToggle.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
    menuToggle.disabled=true
    let menuState = menu.dataset.menuState
    if(menuState==='closed'){
        menu.dataset.menuState='opened'
        setTimeout(() => {
            menuToggle.disabled=false
        }, 500);
    }else{
        menu.classList.add('animate_close')
        setTimeout(() => {
            menu.classList.remove('animate_close')
            menu.dataset.menuState='closed'
            menuToggle.disabled=false
        }, 500);
    }
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

.menu {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: fit-content;
}
.menu {
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu[data-menu-state="closed"] {
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
.menu[data-menu-state="opened"] {
    animation: openMenu .5s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    background-color: green;
}
.menu.animate_close{
    background-color: rgb(0, 30, 128);
    animation: closeMenu .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes openMenu {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}

@keyframes closeMenu {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <label for="menu_toggle">Menu Toggle</label>
    <input id="menu_toggle" type="checkbox" class="menu_toggle">
    <div class="menu_container">
        <div class="menu" data-menu-state="closed">
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
                <li>Item3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
   
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```